# OOP design preference regarding parent/child interaction

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a music notation app which has is a music staff class (CCNode) and a note class (CCSprite).

Notes are added to the music staff like:

```
// MusicStaff.m
[self addChild:note];
```

Notes have a particle emitter, and this needs to be added to the parent..  I am of the opinion that doing something like:

```
// Note.m
[self.musicStaff addChild:self.emitter];
```

is not cool because I don't like the idea of notes controlling the staff--- I like to think of the staff as the one in control of what children it has.

I honestly feel like this particle emitter should be a child of Note, since it technically is part of the note, not part of the music staff-- so adding it to the music staff inherently feels wrong.  However, from what I understand about cocos2d, although you can add a child to a CCSprite, the sprites do not manage the drawing of their children, so this particle emitter would not be visible.

That said, since as far as I know the only way to go about this is to add the emitter to the staff, I would prefer doing:

```
// MusicStaff.m
[self addChild:note];
[self addChild:note.emitter];
```

However, a team member on my project feels this is "backwards" and "dumb", and that the note should add the emitter directly to its parent.  I just seeking some feedback as to if my thoughts on this are indeed "backwards" and "dumb", or if I have a valid point…

Also I am curious if there is another way to solve this problem, like adding the emitter directly to the note and making it draw its children somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of object-oriented design, if the Emitter is created by its parent the Note, I don't think it should add itself to the Staff. If anyone has to talk to the Staff, let it be its direct child, the Note. Even better, make the Note respond to questions asked by the Staff, so in the end the Staff controls what it wants to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the particles as children of the sprite and they will be drawn. Whatever resource gave you the idea that child nodes are not drawn is wrong.

What I think you may have misunderstood is the issue of sprite batching. In that case, when you do use CCSpriteBatchNode, you can only add CCSprite objects to the batch node and the batch node's children. So in that case trying to add a particle effect or any other node as child of a sprite-batched sprite will cause an assertion in cocos2d telling you that this is illegal.

As for the "issue of dumbness": Neither option is really dumb, but adding the emitter to the parent has a minor benefit in that the note takes control over what is inherently the note's responsibility: managing the lifetime of the note's particle effect.

Comment: So..  if Note was going to be a CCSpriteBatchNode, how would one go about adding a particle effect to it?  There's no option but to add it directly to the staff object?